# Flutter - How to convert a String value to LatLng type using GMaps?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, double, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to convert a `String` value to a LatLng type to add Polylines inside a google map.
I am using this way:

```
List<LatLng> list = new List<LatLng>(); 
list.add(new LatLng(double.tryParse(stringArray[0]), double.tryParse(stringArray[1]));
```

my problem is that I have this values '-103.43202524,19.6326681' and when I print that list, I get
'-90,19.6326681' and no matter what number is in the 1rst value I always get '-90'

[image: enter to see the attached image]

Can someone help me please?

Comment: run `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latitude ranges from `[-90, 90]`, so when you input `-103` it's setting it to the nearest valid value, `-90`. Assuming you meant to have the *longitude* be `-103`, you need to switch the argument order when creating the `LatLng` object.

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't realize the order of the coords!!